# Windows 8.1 Desktop Waking from Sleep

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep

I put my computer to sleep this afternoon and I was in the same room and throughout the afternoon the fans would spin up as though the computer was waking from sleep, then it would spin down again and remain "sleeping" for another period of time until it would do the same again. I just went out and returned to my PC being fully awake, so I turned the monitors on and did some checks on the command prompt:

[image]

I also checked my Device Manager settings and neither my mouse/keyboard/network has the ability to wake my PC.

Question:  Why do my fans spin up and down again during sleep mode?/Why is my PC waking from sleep by itself?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @vembutech I think he's asking why the fans spin up and spin down at times while the computer is asleep?

Comment: Sorry yes, I was thinking about not  missing any details, and I actually forgot to ask the question!